# Error on execute script

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT ClientId,
       CONCAT(FirstName,' ', MiddleName,' ', LastName) as FullName,
       SexId,
       Birthday,
       (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ChildBirthdays WHERE ChildBirthdays.Client_Id = Clients.Id) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS HasChild,
       CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount,
       CalculatedProperties_LastVisit,
       CalculatedProperties_TotalSpent,
       (CASE WHEN (CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount > 0) THEN CONVERT(decimal(10,2),CalculatedProperties_TotalSpent / CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount) ELSE 0 END) AS AverageSpent,
       (SELECT Cards.Id, 
               (SELECT [Sum] FROM Accounts WHERE Accounts.CardId = Cards.Id) AS [SumFromAccounts]
        FROM Cards WHERE Clients.Id = Cards.ClientId) AS CardsId   
FROM Clients
```

Error: `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

How can I change the query to make it work? I need client's account sum.

[image]

Comment: The error is probably misleading in this case. Try aliasing the `[sum]` in your subquery like `[sum] as [Sum1]`.

Comment: What's the error on your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this bit:

```
 (SELECT Cards.Id, 
               (SELECT [Sum] FROM Accounts WHERE Accounts.CardId = Cards.Id) AS [SumFromAccounts]
        FROM Cards WHERE Clients.Id = Cards.ClientId) AS CardsId
```

You can't return multiple values in this type of select.

Try using APPLY:

```
    SELECT ClientId,
           CONCAT(FirstName,' ', MiddleName,' ', LastName) as FullName,
           SexId,
           Birthday,
           (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ChildBirthdays WHERE ChildBirthdays.Client_Id = Clients.Id) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS HasChild,
           CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount,
           CalculatedProperties_LastVisit,
           CalculatedProperties_TotalSpent,
           (CASE WHEN (CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount > 0) THEN CONVERT(decimal(10,2),CalculatedProperties_TotalSpent / CalculatedProperties_OrdersCount) ELSE 0 END) AS AverageSpent,
           Cards.CardsId,
           Cards.[SumFromAccounts]

    FROM Clients

OUTER APPLY (SELECT Cards.Id AS CardsId,  
                   (SELECT [Sum] FROM Accounts WHERE Accounts.CardId = Cards.Id) AS [SumFromAccounts]
            FROM Cards WHERE Clients.Id = Cards.ClientId) AS Cards
```